# how to show a success and error messages in php if they are within div with inline css attribute display:none

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very simple form for a newsletter subscription. Validation is done both in jquery using the latest plugin version and php.  I have also included ajax to stop page from refreshing. Jquery part of the code seems to be working fine. However, I have a few other problems;-

1. Success and error messages don't show in php,
2. PHP validation picks only 2 error messages "Name is required" and "Invalid email format". When I enter name the error message goes away but when I enter the correct email format the error message stays.
3. When I submit the form it goes to the top of the page, i.e. refreshes and ajax doesn't stop it from doing so.
4. When form is submitted it also changes heading colours on the entire page to green (i.e. 'successMessage' colour).

My html and php code are in the same file called index.php . The jquery code is in a separate file. I've also inserted my css coding just in case (also a separate file).

I've spent quite a few days searching the web for possible answers to my questions but no success. I'm stuck so please help. Thank you in advance.

html

```
<div class="container" id="footer-container">

    <h5>Join My Mailing List!</h5>

<form role="form" id="subscribe_form" method="post" action="index.php">

    <div class="form-group" id="form">

        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-5" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" muted>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="nameErr"><? echo $nameErr; ?></label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" muted>
        <label class="error" for="email" id="emailErr"><? echo $emailErr; ?></label>

  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-dark"
 style="width:26rem" >Subscribe Now</button>



    <div id="successMessage" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;"><h6>Your email has been successfully added to the mailing list!</h6></div>
    <div id="errorMessage" style="width:100%; display:none;"> <h5>Error</h5> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>

   </form> 

   </div>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {

    $("form").validate({

        //set validation rules
    rules: {

      name: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

    },

    messages: {
      name: "Please enter your name",
      email: {
        required: "Please provide your email",
        email: "Please enter a valid email"
        }
      },


        submitHandler: function(form) {

             $(form).submit(function(event) {
// Stop the browser from submitting the form.
event.preventDefault();

        $("#successMessage").show();        
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
        })   

  }); 

  }

});

});
```

php

```
<?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $email = "";

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
 $nameErr = "Name is required";
 } 
   // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
  }

 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $emailErr = "Email is required";
} 
  // check if e-mail address is well-formed
  (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
  }


 // Set the recipient email address.

    $recipient = "myemail@hotmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {

        echo '<div id="successMessage">';

    } else {

         echo '<div id="errorMessage">';
    }
  }
 ?>
```

css

```
    #footer-container {

        width: 450px;
        height: 320px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;


    }

    #footer {

        background-color: #e5dcdc;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
    }



    .btn {

        font-size: 120%;
        font-style: italic;

     }


    h5 {

        font-family: 'Tillana', cursive;

    }


    #image-ref {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 7em
    }


    .error {

        margin-top: 4px;
        color: #ef2327;

    }

    #successMessage {

        padding-top: 15px;
        color: #3baf51;

    }

    #errorMessage {

        padding-top: 8px;
        color: #ef2327;
    }
```

I'm not sure how jquery plugin interacts with php.  Assume I still need a server side validation but the two do not work in my code.

Comment: What's the point of the `$(form).submit(function(event) {` part?  Isn't that going to do a "true" form submit, which isn't what you want?

Comment: Oh, yeah, good point. I was thinking of having an error message at the beginning but then took it.  Not sure if I do need to replicate an error message in jquery?